# EF Core FromSqlRaw not executing stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am using EF Core Version 3.1.9.

The code shown here is to execute a stored procedure - but it does not seem to work:

```
var test1 = "abc";
var test2 = "xyz";

EmpResponse emp = await _context.Emp
                                .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE EMPS..sel_keys @param1 = 20000, @param2 = {0}, @param3 = {1}", test1, test2)
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I get this error:

> FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.
>
> Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client side.

I found the below document and it suggest to modify using `AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#fromsql

But since I am using `await`, the above suggestion does not work.
Could someone suggest how to do it with `await`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to `await` a call to `ToListAsync()` and then apply `{First|Single|Last}{OrDefault}`, e.g.

```cs
var emp = (await _context.Emp
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE EMPS..sel_keys @param1 = 20000, @param2 = {0}, @param3 = {1}", test1, test2)
    .ToListAsync())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

In general they (EF Core designers) are expecting you to just insert `AsAsyncEnumerable()`

```cs
var emp = await _context.Emp
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE EMPS..sel_keys @param1 = 20000, @param2 = {0}, @param3 = {1}", test1, test2)
    .AsAsyncEnumerable() // <--
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

but that first requires installing additionally [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/4.1.1) package, and second - once you do that, you start getting a lot of *ambiguous call* compile-time errors when you access `DbSet`s in queries, because they implement both `IQueryable<T>` and `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`.

So you'd better stay with the first solution until this gets resolved (I think it would be in EF Core 6).